# sql select inside count - without join

Tags: sql-server

There is a table called: **`IDs`** and another table called `Entries`.

Not all ids from `Ids` have entries. I do want to count how many entries have ALL the ids. if an Id has no entry I want to print 0.

Ids have PK: ID and Entries have a column ID.

If I joined them I get only the IDS having entries, but I want to get all of the IDS.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `INNER JOIN` you can achieve this by using `LEFT JOIN` instead

**EXAMPLE**

```
/* Declare Temperory table for data storage */

DECLARE @MasterTable AS TABLE
(
ID INT 
)

DECLARE @EntryTable AS TABLE
(
EntryID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
,MasterId INT
)

--Insert entries to Master Table

INSERT INTO @MasterTable
SELECT 1
UNION
SELECT 2
UNION
SELECT 3
UNION
SELECT 4

--Insert details into details table for only 1 and 2
INSERT INTO @EntryTable
(
MasterId

)
SELECT 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 2
UNION ALL
SELECT 3
UNION ALL
SELECT 3

SELECT
     ID
    ,COUNT(EntryTable.MasterId) AS EntryCount
FROM
@MasterTable MainTable
LEFT JOIN
@EntryTable EntryTable
ON
MainTable.ID = EntryTable.MasterId
GROUP BY
ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `left join`

```
select ids.id, count(entries.id)
from ids
left join entries on entries.id = ids.id
group by ids.id
```

Also see [this great explanation of joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, EntriesCount.entriesCount 
FROM IDs 
     OUTER APPLY (
          SELECT COUNT(id) entriesCount 
          FROM Entries 
          WHERE Entries.ids = IDs.id 
          ) AS EntriesCount
```

outer apply let's you use the id from IDs in the 'where' condition from Entries.